# Voltage increased suddenly

Tags: voltage, power

Today suddenly the voltage increased too much in our area and many people's TV, Lights and Others things get damaged ( mine too). What happened and what to do? 
What to do in future to be safe so that none of my electric item get damaged?

Comment: A good insurance and lawyer.

Comment: I wouldn't claim an insurance for a broken TV, though.. The premium increase doesn't worth it.. In my area at least.

Answer (score 1):

A few.

1. Move out of the area.
2. Live off grid.
3. Buy a whole house regulator.
4. Buy regulator for individual appliances.
5. Buy quality appliances that can sustain a surge.
6. Unplug your appliance when not in use - not 100 percent effective.

...

Answer (score 1):

What did happen was some fault on the power 3-phase transformer which feeds the local power lines in your neighborhood, some fuses have blown asymmetrically. It happens during thunderstorms.

To protect from this, you might want to install a massive surge protector, search for "[household surge protector](https://www.google.com/search?q=household%20surge%20protector)". They are installed right at your house power junction cabinet, and are a bit pricey, $200-$300.

Answer (score 1):

Another consideration, buy insurance.

Also, gather your neighbors that are affected by the surge. Send a formal request to the power company to compensate your damage appliance.